# Concatenate String and Integer in Swift

Tags: swift, concatenation

I would have expected concatenation between different types to be straightforward in Swift, but apparently not. What is the workaround for this?

```
var boy = "Bart Simpson"
var age = 7
print(boy + " is " + age)
```

Comment: `print(boy + " is " + "\(age)")`

Comment: Learn the basics, it's in the Swift doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID292

Answer (score 15, accepted):

very easy, wrap all printable objects in `\( )`

```
let boy = "Bart Simpson"
let age = 7
print("\(boy) is \(age)")
```

Comment: You can also: `println("\("Bart Simpson") is \(7)")` If you don't want to declare those temporary vaiables but simply print out values directly

Answer (score 6):

```
let boy = "Bart Simpson"
let age = 7

let sentence = String(format:"%@ is %d", boy, age)
println(sentence) // "Bart Simpson is 7"
```